# Replacing Blank members with '?' in SSAS

Tags: ssas, cube

How can I display a dimension with blank member as '?'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to **NOT** have blanks in your dimension. i.e., when you build your dimension table, replace the blanks with appropriate value. Commonly, "N/A" or "Not Applicable" is used.

In your SQL, you would normally use ISNULL function,

```
SELECT ISNULL(<your column name>, 'N/A')
```

Also, see this Kimball design tip:

https://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/02/design-tip-43-dealing-with-nulls-in-the-dimensional-model/

> Putting a null in these fields can be confusing to the user, as it will appear as a blank on reports and pull-down menus, and require special query syntax to find. Instead, we recommend substituting an appropriately descriptive string, like “Unknown” or “Not provided.”